# Query time calculation in SQL

Tags: java, sql, tree

I have a SQL query in the format of tree (A⨝B)⨝(C⨝D)⨝(E⨝F)⨝(G⨝H)⨝(I⨝J) containing different joins.I want to know that is there any method that we can find the time for each join operation separately like how much time sub expression (A⨝B) can take. Or (C⨝D) can take. instead of whole expression. Or how can we find the time for only the sub expression (A⨝B)⨝(C⨝D). I have converted my SQL query into tree by using Java language.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A look at the explain plan could maybe answer your questions about the query and its components.

Comment: What's the database? The answer is very database-specific.

Comment: I guess you are talking about "execution time", right?

Comment: Yes i am talking about execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is just run all possible combinations you want and measure them. Why? Read on.

Databases are very tricky when it comes to execute queries. Some of them focus on giving you the first matching entries (suitable for web pages, for example); other ones go for the whole resultset, skipping indexes altogether and reading disk pages instead (optimal way).

A different approach is to get the *COST* of a SQL statement. In general, using `EXPLAIN PLAN < my_select >` you'll get the details about the cost of the plan. Not the execution time, but a relative cost. The cost doesn't have any meaning outside the database but helps the SQL Optimizer to decide which execution plan seems to be the best one.

Also, database caching plays a huge role. The second time you run a query it may run much faster than the first time, since the database (or the OS) still has all the disk pages in memory.

Finally, indexes can greatly speed up the queries. You'll notice the (big) difference in query speed if you have the right ones created, compared to having none of them.

In short, you'll need to measure them and see.